# Updating Member of an Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, iphone, swiftui

Newbie here.
My problem simplified:

I have a Person struct consisting of 2 strings - first and last name.
An initial array with a few persons (ex. "Bob" "Smith", "Joe" "Johnson", etc.)
A list view showing each member.

Clicking on a row in the list shows a detail view - call it "person card" view - which shows the first name and last name.

I then have a modal view to edit these variables.
Currently the Save button on the modal only closes the modal.  However, because I am using bindings on the modal view to the values on the "person card" view, the "person card" view is updated with the changed data when the modal closes.

The list view though still shows the original value(s) and not the updated data (as I expect).  I know that I have to add as method to the save function but I'm not sure what.  I know how to insert and append to an array but I can't find an update array method.

FYI - The data model I am using is a "store" instance of a class that is an ObservableObject.  I have that variable declared as an EnvironmentObject on each view.

Here is the code as requested:

```
struct PatientData: Identifiable
{
    let id = UUID()

    var patientName: String
    var age: String

}



let patientDataArray: [PatientData] = 

[  
    PatientData(patientName: "Charles Brown", age: "68"),
    PatientData(patientName: "Jim Morrison", age: "36"),
]



final class PatientDataController: ObservableObject
{
@Published var patients = patientDataArray
{



struct PatientList: View
{
    @EnvironmentObject var patientDataController: PatientDataController
    @State private var showModalSheet = false

    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            List
            {
                ForEach(patientDataController.patients)
                { patientData in    NavigationLink(destination: PatientInfoCard(patientData: patientData))
                { PatientListCell(patientData: patientData) }
                }
                .onMove(perform: move)
                .onDelete(perform: delete)

                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Patient List"))
            }



struct PatientInfoCard: View
{
    @EnvironmentObject var patientDataController: PatientDataController

    @State var patientData: PatientData
    @State private var showModalSheet = false

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8)
        {  // Change to patientDataArray???
            Text(patientData.patientName)
                .font(.largeTitle)
            BasicInfo(patientData: patientData)
            Spacer()
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .padding()

        // Can't push Edit button more than once
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action:
            {self.showModalSheet = true})
                {Text("Edit")})
            .sheet(isPresented: $showModalSheet)
        {
            EditPatientModal(patientData: self.$patientData, showModalSheet: self.$showModalSheet)
                .environmentObject(self.patientDataController)

        }
    }
}



struct EditPatientModal: View
{
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var patientDataController: PatientDataController
    @Binding var patientData: PatientData
    @Binding var showModalSheet: Bool

    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            VStack(alignment: .leading)
            {
                Text("Name")
                    .font(.headline)
                TextField("enter name", text: $patientData.patientName)


                Text("Age")
                    .font(.headline)
                TextField("enter age", text: $patientData.age)

            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Edit Patient"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: Button("Cancel")
                    { self.cancel() },
                trailing: Button("Save")
                    { self.save() } )
        }
    }

    private func save()
    {

        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
```

Here is my updated code:

```
class PatientData: ObservableObject, Identifiable
{
    let id = UUID()

    @Published var patientName = ""
    @Published var age = ""

    init(patientName: String, age: String)
    {
        self.patientName = patientName
        self.age = age

    }
}



let patientDataArray: [PatientData] =
[
    PatientData(patientName: "Charles Brown", age: "68"),
    PatientData(patientName: "Jim Morrison", age: "36")    
]



final class PatientDataController: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var patients = patientDataArray
}



struct PatientList: View
{
    @EnvironmentObject var patientDataController: PatientDataController
    @EnvironmentObject var patientData: PatientData
    @State private var showModalSheet = false

    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            List
            {
                ForEach(self.patientDataController.patients.indices)
                { idx in
                NavigationLink(destination: PatientInfoCard(patientData: self.$patientDataController.patients[idx]))

 /*Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<PatientData>' to expected argument type 'PatientData'*/ <-- My one error message; in NavigationLink

                { PatientListCell(patientData: self.$patientDataController.patients[idx]) }
                }
                .onMove(perform: move)
                .onDelete(perform: delete)

                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Patient List"))
            }
        .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton())



struct PatientInfoCard: View
{
    @EnvironmentObject var patientDataController: PatientDataController

    @Binding var patientData: PatientData
    @State private var showModalSheet = false

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8)
        {  
            Text(patientData.patientName)
                .font(.largeTitle)
            BasicInfo(patientData: patientData)
            Spacer()
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action:
            {self.showModalSheet = true})
                {Text("Edit")})
            .sheet(isPresented: $showModalSheet)
        {
            EditPatientModal(patientData: self.$patientData, showModalSheet: self.$showModalSheet)
                .environmentObject(self.patientDataController)

        }
    }
}


struct BasicInfo: View
{
    @EnvironmentObject var patientDataController: PatientDataController

    @State var patientData: PatientData

    var patientDataIndex: Int
    {
        patientDataController.patients.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == patientData.id })!
    }

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8)
        {

            Text("Age:")
                .font(.headline)
            Text(patientData.age)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)

        }
    }
}



struct EditPatientModal: View
{
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var patientDataController: PatientDataController

    @Binding var patientData: PatientData
    @Binding var showModalSheet: Bool

    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            VStack(alignment: .leading)
            {
                Text("Name")
                    .font(.headline)
                TextField("enter name", text: $patientData.patientName)


                Text("Age")
                    .font(.headline)
                TextField("enter age", text: $patientData.age)

            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Edit Patient"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: Button("Cancel")
                    { self.cancel() },
                trailing: Button("Save")
                    { self.save() } )
        }
    }

    private func save()
    {

        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
```

Comment: Hi Cubert, Your problem seems easy to fix but can you please add some code for us to work with? or create a reproducible demo? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 2 things in your code.

Your struct needs to be `ObservableObject` otherwise any changes happen to it will not get effected and in order for it to be `ObservableObject` it has to be a class so first change:

```
class PatientData: ObservableObject, Identifiable
{
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var patientName: String
    @Published var age: String

    init(patientName: String, age: String) {
        self.patientName = patientName
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

I understand you have an `environmentObject` which is publishing, but it's only publishing changes to the array, meaning adding or removing items but not to individual `patientData` objects.

2nd thing to change is in your `forEach loop` you need pass `Patient` as a `Bind` and in order to do that you have to loop through indices and then access the data through `Bind`

```
NavigationView
        {
            if(self.patientDataController.patients.count > 0) {
                    List {
                        ForEach(self.patientDataController.patients.enumerated().map({$0}), id:\.element.id) { idx, patient in
                            NavigationLink(destination: PatientInfoCard(patientData: self.$patientDataController.patients[idx])) {
                                Text(patient.patientName)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton())
                } else {
                    Text("List is empty")
                }
        }
```

Let us know if this doesn't work

Comment: Thanks.  I noticed that I didn’t add in my code for the “PatientInfoCard” struct (or “PersonCard” as I was calling it in my abbreviated description of the problem).  I’m at work currently so when I get home I’ll add that code in and make the 2 suggested changes.  I had no idea that the struct declaring the variables had to be an ObservableObject, too (and hence a class).  I thought only the array of those variables had to be.

Comment: No worries at all, I noticed that but I don't think it would make a difference but if what I proposed doesn't work then update the code and I should be able to help.

Comment: Note:  I added the "PatientInfoCard" struct in my code - not sure it matters though.

Comment: Got it, make sure to make the changes I proposed and if it doesn’t work I will look at your PatientInfoCard

Comment: So one error message in my updated code I posted below.

Comment: Make sure in PatientListCell you have defined PatientData as a Binding not State

Comment: I do have PatientData in PatientListCell as a Binding.  If I remove the "$" from NavigationLink: PatientInfoCard, it works but the data displayed in the BasicInfo view part of the PatientInfoCard only gets correctly displayed if I go back to the list view first and then back to the PatientInfoCard view.  BUT if I change the patient name on the edit modal, it updates on the PatientInfoCard immediately because that piece of data is not part of the BasicInfo view.

Comment: Alright, I will fix it up soon. I am just at work right now.

Comment: I moved all the data displayed in the BasicInfo view into the PatientInfoCard view rather than "referencing" it as "BasicInfo(patientData: patientData)" and it works.  I had to use groupings to get around the 10 members to a VStack limit (Remember, I pared down my code to show the basics of it for the problem).  I was trying to follow good SwiftUI form by refactoring views into subviews (like I did with the List cell view) but it bit me in the ass here.

Comment: So things moving fast now.  LOL.  Because I got editing working I implemented adding a new patient.  It works but my list only displays the first 4 items in the array (like it's stuck at that number because that's how many items are in it originally).  If I add an item at index 0, the last item falls off the list and will only show again if I delete one of the other 3.

Comment: It's a good practice to separate your views! You can update your code to include `PatientListCell` if you want me to take a look at that piece! but if it works then thats great :D but try to refactor into sub-views at a later point so you can practice.

Comment: Yes it is the same code that I list under "Here is my updated code".  I also discovered that if I try to delete a row I get an "Index out of range" error.  I'm thinking that the 2 issues are related (the deleting row problem and the not displaying more than 4 rows problem).

Comment: @Cubert please find updated code in the post. instead of only looping through indices, we are now looping through an object that will give us an index so we use in binding and a patient object to use in displaying the data.

Comment: Ahhhh....that makes sense given that I had to change my data structure to a class instead of a struct.

Now the only error I am getting is in the NavigationLink code:  "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<PatientData>' to expected argument type 'PatientData'"

NavigationLink(destination: PatientInfoCard(patientData: self.$patientDataController.patients[idx]))

Comment: Muhand,
I removed the $ from the navigation link to the PatientInfoCard and it works.  Everything works and I am happy.  I thank you profusely for your help.  You can probably tell I am very new to this.  I started dabbling in coding for iOS back when the first SDK was released about 6 months before the App Store.  I wanted to be one of those first 500 apps.  For various reasons I put it aside.  I've gone back and played around a little bit over the years but decided 2 months ago I was really going to do it.  So I spent a month reading about Swift and SwiftUI while I waited for.....

Comment: ...my new MacBook Pro to arrive.  Then on May 15th I started my first app, which actually isn't this one.  I got it all clusterfscked and this one has the same foundation as that one so I started on this one with a fresh look, a minute amount of experience, and better construction.  Now I'm going to go back and rewrite the first one.  I'm close to the point where they will diverge because they have very different purposes but are both navigation-list based.  I have many ideas and who knows if any of them will make it into the App Store - I'd just be happy to have something working, use it.....

Comment: ...myself, and show my coworkers, "Hey, I made this."  My daytime job is primary care physician.  I live in Philadelphia (need to fill out my profile for this site) and maybe next time I'm in NYC I'll meet you and buy you a beer (if you drink, I don't).  But I appreciate your time and help and my bugging you is done.  Over and out.  o7  Thanks!

Comment: I applaude you for taking the time to learn something new! its great! I think there is nothing in the world better than seeing your work come to life and there are users. There is a special feeling when you complete something, so I truly congratulate you. I will surely be one of your first adapters! If you do need help, dont hesitate to contact me. I might take time responding but I will definitely respond! Good luck on the rest